# Can I use Azure App Service Domain on AKS?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-dns

I have brought a domain using Azure App Service.
Can I use that domain on AKS? or will there be a legal issue?

If there will be legal issue. Can I transfer that domain to, for example GoDaddy?

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#accept-terms-and-purchase), you could buy the domain on app service domain but the domain is registered by GoDaddy and seamlessly hosted on [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview). You can find it via App Service Domain->Overview->Manage DNS records->Delegated to Azure DNS zone on the portal.

> App Service Domains use GoDaddy for domain registration and Azure DNS
>   to host the domains. In addition to the domain registration fee, usage
>   charges for Azure DNS apply

So you could use this domain on AKS just like for an externally purchased domain. you just need to add or modify your records on Azure DNS. It is not mandatory to migrate to Azure DNS hosting. If you want to host your domain to another domain provider, you need to go to their website to procure domain hosting solution.

You also could follow the steps below to transfer out the domain:

- Login to Azure portal
- Select your App Service domain that you wish to transfer out
- Go to **Advance management for the domain**
- Click your domain -> manage
- Under "Additional Settings" a. Unlock your domain. Click on Edit for "Domain lock" and turn it Off. b. Click on "transfers out".

Read more details [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html).